# repeat a command for a block

Tags: vim

I have been working with vim for 4 weeks and I am wondering how to do this:

I wanted to comment a code in ruby adding a '#'. I could do a '.' for all lines. But what if I have a lot of lines to comment?

Is there some command I can do to do it on a block?

Not: This doesn't mean only for putting a '#'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do visual block mode. ctrl+v at the beginning of the line then move the cursor down as many lines as you want to comment out, hit shift+i then # then escape and it will put a # in front of all those lines. Personally I use tComment. There's lots of plugins available for comment handling.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173

Comment: +1 for a simple solution using functionality already built in to Vim. Visual Block mode is very powerful.

Comment: I had to press ESC twice for the visual block insert to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need blockwise selection.

Start selecting with CTRL-V, press 4j, and then I (capital i).

Comment: @Thorpe Obazee: How does it differ from the solution you accepted?

Comment: sorry. but the your answer is incomplete. You missed when I type '#'.

Comment: @Thorpe Obazee: no, it is not incomplete. It indicates you where to start. Also in vim use `help blockwise-examples`.

Comment: Benoit. Yes where to start only. Thanks. I'll upvote but I need to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

For all lines you can do this :

```
:%s/^\(.*)/#\1
```

for a block you can do it with interactive choice :

```
:%s/^\(.*)/#\1/c
```

Vim will prompt to replace at each match (answer y or n)

I guess there is a way to do it with line number, or maybe groups of line but I don't have the idea right now.

EDIT: So for blocks (as comments suggested it) do :

```
vip (in normal mode to select the block)
:'<,'>s/^\(.*\)/#\1/
```

also

```
:'<,'>s/^/#/
```

Comment: Or simply `%s/^/#/`... To do between certain line numbers, just pass a range like you're already passing. `%` is a range, equivalent to `1,$` (first line to the last). `40,78s/^/#/` acts on lines 40 to 78.

Comment: @sidyll Ah nice! Now, we should find one that mean : currently selected lines I guess.

Comment: `'<,'>s/^/#/` :-) If you are with the lines selected, `'<` and `'>` are automatically inserted when you press `:`. They mean beginning and end of selection.

Comment: Edited to provide a better answer. Thanks @sidyll

Answer (score 0):

Answer has already been accepted, but you might find this useful.  `<leader>/` to comment a block and `<leader>?` to uncomment.  Works in visual mode, or with normal motion, like `3,/` to comment 3 lines, assuming comma as your mapleader.

```
map <leader>/ :s/^\(\s*\)/# \1/<CR>:nohl<CR>"
map <leader>? :s/^\(\s*\)# /\1/<CR>:nohl<CR>"
```